# How to space out my websocket updates via RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs

My Angular component displays a scoreboard that receives updates via websocket anytime the scoreboard changes. The scoreboard changes anytime any voter submits a ballot. The scoreboard updates could come across the websocket at any interval. My scoreboard's animation takes 1000ms. I would like an RxJS way of being sure that there will always be at least 1000ms between iterations of my `tap()` operator running so that my animations can run. If a flurry of scoreboard updates come through the socket rapid-fire, I would like to handle this one of two ways: a) The updates queue up and are executed one-by-one every 1000ms. b) Every 1000ms, if there have been any new updates, apply the latest update, and ignore the others.

```
// Scoreboard updates are coming in via websocket anytime the scoreboard changes.
// The scoreboard changes anytime a voter submits a ballot.
this.scoreboardService.scoreboardUpdates$
  .pipe(
    tap((scoreboardUpdate: Scoreboard) => {
      // Apply update to the scoreboard
      // Scoreboard animation takes 1000ms to complete
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: You could make use of `throttleTime`

Comment: can you share the code that performs the animations as well?

Comment: The animation code is unfortunately not reactive, so I have no way of tying it into the reactive pipeline. But I do know that the animation is 1000ms.

Comment: @Sergey, please see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58921209/how-to-space-out-my-websocket-updates-via-rxjs#comment104105827_58921938) to the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
this.scoreboardService.scoreboardUpdates$
  .pipe(
    throttleTime(1000),
    tap((scoreboardUpdate: Scoreboard) => {
      // Apply update to the scoreboard
      // Scoreboard animation takes 1000ms to complete
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: He maybe wants to use debounceTime rather then throttleTime (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html)

Comment: `throttleTime(1000)` ignores any updates that happen during the 1000ms duration. Let's say that the scoreboard sits there for a while without any updates coming through, then suddenly 2 updates come through. The first update would come through, activate the 1000ms throttle period, and reach the `tap()`. The second update would immediately come through during the throttle period, thus being ignored. Let's say no other updates come through for five minutes. Update2 would never display on the scoreboard.

Comment: `debounceTime(1000)` is closer to working, but it has a different problem. Let's imagine that the scoreboard update traffic is heavy...updates are coming through every 500ms. No update would ever run, because `debounceTime(1000)` is waiting for a 1000ms break in the action. Once a 1000ms break happens, it will display the latest update on the scoreboard, but in high-traffic situations, this may not happen for long periods of time.

Comment: @JWess There is an options parameter in `throttleTime` which allows you proceccing trailing value. What means that even if both of them hit in `1ms` the first and the last will be processed in that case. You can read more about it here https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/throttleTime

Comment: @JWess I can recommend reading comments in source of methods. In PhpStorm you can Ctrl+Click on an operator or a static method of RxJs and follow to the source. It has a well described code. I find it much cleaner and rich rather than what I've ever found on the Internet

Comment: The `{ leading: false, trailing: true }` enables bahavior (b) described in the question: "Every 1000ms, if there have been any new updates, apply the latest update, and ignore the others."